# Android RequestFocus() Ineffective

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I want the EditText in my application to have the cursor by default when the application starts.
I tried using

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/idInput"
    android:layout_width="480dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

and also

```
userIdInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.idInput);
userIdInput.setFocusable(true);
userIdInput.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
userIdInput.requestFocus();
```

But none of it seems to have any effect. The cursor is nowhere visible when the application starts and I have to manually click the EditText to make the cursor appear on it.

Where could I be possibly go wrong ?

By the way, I am developing for Android 4.0.3 tablets.

Comment: Have you give the `<requestFocus />` to which `EditText`'s in xml file you want to set the Focus?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this

```
userIdInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.idInput);

userIdInput.post(new Runnable() 
    {
      public void run() 
       {
        userIdInput .requestFocus();
       }
    });
```

Comment: Can anyone explain why this is helpful and/or necessary?

Comment: The thing is hidden in the choreography of Android activity life cycle methods and timing. The onResume is the last one to run before the UI is visible, but when onResume finishes the UI is still not ready - it is ready in the event queue to be rendered.

Putting requestFocus in one of the life cycle methods, makes it run before the UI is ready.
If you use view.post(...), the runnable is put in the event queue that is guaranteed to run after the life cycle method where it has been called from.

So, make sure view.post(new Runnable ()....) .... is in onResume, then your app will run correctly.